# Regex to match the value optionally enclosed by double quotes

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have 3 columns delimited by white spaces but the second field is optionally enclosed by double quotes.

I want to extract the 1st field, 2nd field(value within the double quotes) and third field, sometimes the 2nd field value might not be enclosed within the double quotes in that case just return the existing value.

**Sample Input**

```
1a "2a 2.1a 2.2a" 3a
4b "5.5b 5.6b 5.7b" 6b
7c 8c 9c
```

**Final output**

Matching Information are
**1st row match**

```
\1 1a
\2 2a 2.1a 2.2a
\3 3a
```

**2nd row match**

```
\1 4b
\2 5.5b 5.6b 5.7b
\3 6b
```

**3rd row match**

```
\1 7c
\2 8c
\3 9c
```

I tried the  below regex and it works fine for the first two inputs but the third line is not matched, Can someone help me to solve this issue?

**Regex i tried:**

```
([a-z0-9]+)\s+"([a-z0-9\s.]+)"\s+([a-z0-9]+)
```

**Link:**

https://regex101.com/r/rN4uB4/1

Comment: What programming language are you using?  There's probably a CSV module that would handle this for you.  If you were in Perl, you'd use Text::CSV for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that it is is optional that the values are quoted.

You can parse this using:

```
([a-z0-9]+)\s+"?([a-z0-9\s.]+)"?\s+([a-z0-9]+)
```

The `?` means the group (or character `"` in this case) is optional.

It makes me however wonder what you want to do? This looks a lot like `bash` argument parsing. Sometimes you can take advantage of libraries for this...

**EDIT**

@PetSerAl brings up a valid point: both quotes `"` are independent of each other, so:

```
4b "5.5b 5.6b 5.7b 6b
4b 5.5b 5.6b 5.7b" 6b
```

Will match as well, you can solve this by introducing additional *capture groups*:

```
([a-z0-9]+)\s+("([a-z0-9\s.]+)"|([a-z0-9\s.]+))\s+([a-z0-9]+)
```

In that case the old capture groups map on the new as follows:

- `\1 -> \1`
- `\2 -> \3 (with quotes) or \4 (without quotes)`
- `\3 -> \5`

One can also use `\2` for the old `\2`, but the new `\2` will include the quotes `"` as well if they are part of the string.

It will thus cost more postprocessing to handle them correctly.

Answer (score 5):

You could simply make the quotations [optional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) in your pattern. By following the preceding token with `?` you're telling the regular expression engine to match the preceding between "zero and one" time.

```
([a-z0-9]+)\s+"?([a-z0-9\s.]+)"?\s+([a-z0-9]+)
```

If your language supports it, you could use the branch reset feature. By using this feature, both capturing groups in the alternatives are considered as one capturing group.

```
([a-z0-9]+)\s+(?|"([^"]+)"|([a-z0-9]+))\s+([a-z0-9]+)
```

Comment: Since both quotes a optional independently of each other, this pattern can match incorrect string.

Comment: For example this string `4b "5.5b 5.6b 5.7b 6b` matched by your pattern.

Comment: Yes your regex works fine but both the below solutions are same and also posted at same time. I saw @CommuSoft solution first so i will accept his answer and +1 for you.

Comment: @PetSerAl: well you can resolve this by introducing additional *capture groups*, not without... Will provide an alternative answer.